# Getting git to show specific filenames it is running content filters on

Tags: git, debugging, git-filter

I'm debugging the workings of a configured git content filter (`nbstripout`) and I'm trying to get `GIT_TRACE` to show me the files it's operating on, but it doesn't. Consider:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git pull origin master
[...] removed irrelevant sections of the output
16:49:28.846707 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git merge FETCH_HEAD
16:49:28.849309 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git merge FETCH_HEAD
Updating 1ea49ad..ae0ba93
16:49:28.863291 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: nbstripout
16:49:28.864700 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: nbstripout
16:49:28.866060 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: nbstripout
[...] many more of the same
```

How can I get `GIT_TRACE`'s `run_command` to show the arguments passed to the filter? I looked at various other debug environment variables in git's manual, but I don't see anything that would enable that level of debug.

I'm aware of `git check-attr`, but I'd like to see the run time trace on which files it's running the filter on and with which arguments.

git version 2.17.1

Comment: The [source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/29d9e3e2c47dd4b5053b0a98c891878d398463e3/run-command.c#L614-L639) suggests it should already be printing argv here.

Comment: great idea to look at the source, @torek! I looked at [sq_quote_argv()](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/quote.c#L75) 
which calls `strbuf_grow()` and 
[sq_quote_argv_pretty()](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/quote.c#L87) (which is the one missing the argv trace) doesn't call it - perhaps it should have that call and somehow the argv just disappears?

Comment: These are pretty basic internal functions, they kind of have to work. My guess is that there *aren't* any arguments. Filter functions read stdin and write stdout; arguments, if present, are just informative. Note that modern "process style" filters (eg, Git-LFS) use a streaming protocol to keep one long-running filter going as long as possible, giving it "files" via encoded input streams. Older style filters are run once per file but often get no arguments.

Comment: That would probably explain the lack of `argv` in the trace. This is of course not debug friendly. Thank you for taking me to the source and offering a reasonable explanation, @torek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted this question on the git mailing list and Jeff King [provided a workaround as an answer](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=153541400522793&w=2). With Jeff's permission I'm sharing his answer here:

---

GIT_TRACE should always show the arguments. But unless you specify
arguments in the clean/smudge filter config, then Git won't pass any.
The stdin/stdout stream is all that matters.

So e.g.:

```
  $ echo '* filter=foo' >.gitattributes
  $ git config filter.foo.clean 'myfilter'
  $ GIT_TRACE=1 git add .
  19:42:16.516401 [pid=14112] git.c:415             trace: built-in: git add .
  19:42:16.517454 [pid=14112] run-command.c:637     trace: run_command: myfilter

  $ git config filter.foo.clean 'myfilter --foo'
  $ touch .gitattributes ;# make sure we actually read it again ;)
  $ GIT_TRACE=1 git add .
  19:42:58.122942 [pid=14156] git.c:415             trace: built-in: git add .
  19:42:58.124023 [pid=14156] run-command.c:637     trace: run_command: 'myfilter \
--foo'
```

You can use "%f" to pass the name of the file, like:

```
  $ git config filter.foo.clean 'myfilter %f'
  $ touch .gitattributes
  $ GIT_TRACE=1 git add .
  19:44:51.187177 [pid=14318] git.c:415             trace: built-in: git add .
  19:44:51.188256 [pid=14318] run-command.c:637     trace: run_command: 'myfilter \
'\''.gitattributes'\'''
```

Of course that won't be helpful if your filter actually respects the
argument. For a "clean" filter that might be OK (e.g., if it just tells
your filter to read from the filesystem instead of stdin), but it's
almost certainly not what you want for a "smudge" filter.

You can work around it with some shell hackery:

```
  git config filter.foo.clean 'f() { echo >&2 "cleaning $1"; myfilter ...; }; f %f'
```

and then even without GIT_TRACE, you get:

```
  $ git add .
  cleaning .gitattributes
```

Or if you really just want to trigger for GIT_TRACE, try just this:

```
  $ git config filter.foo.clean 'f() { myfilter; }; f %f'
  19:52:52.874064 [pid=14719] git.c:415             trace: built-in: git add .
  19:52:52.875115 [pid=14719] run-command.c:637     trace: run_command: 'f() { \
myfilter; }; f '\''.gitattributes'\'''
```

There you get the name in the trace output, but the invoked command
doesn't actually do anything with it.

---

So I ended up using:

```
[filter "nbstripout"]
    clean  = "f() { echo >&2 \"clean: nbstripout $1\"; nbstripout; }; f %f"
    smudge = "f() { echo >&2 \"smudge: cat $1\"; cat; }; f %f"
    required = true
```

and now I get the filenames logged when run with `GIT_TRACE=1`, and without it.

---

In a [followup](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=153541789423647&w=2) Jeff suggested that one day git may support this directly and not need a workaround.